# Qiwi API message verification (library requests)

Tags: python, python-requests

I tried to put money on steam with qiwi api, but its giving error: QWPRC-309, i guess that its because of message verification, because i use code from official documentation. How can I put code from message verification to one of fields so code will work? Or I must just use token with transactions without message codes?

This is code from official documentation.

```
import requests
import time

# payment for service provider

def pay_simple_prv(api_access_token, prv_id, to_account, sum_pay):
    s = requests.Session()
    s.headers['Accept'] = 'application/json'
    s.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    s.headers['authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + api_access_token
    postjson = {"id":"","sum": {"amount":"","currency":"643"},"paymentMethod": {"type":"Account","accountId":"643"},"fields": {"account":""}}
    postjson['id'] = str(int(time.time() * 1000))
    postjson['sum']['amount'] = sum_pay
    postjson['fields']['account'] = to_account
    res = s.post('https://edge.qiwi.com/sinap/api/v2/terms/'+prv_id+'/payments', json=postjson)
    return res.json()
pay_simple_prv("token", "steam_id", "steam_name", "sum")
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't find a way to do transactions with sms code verification, so I recommend you just create a new token with transactions, without sms verification and when money is on your profile just move them to your bank account.